# Rename outlook2007 categories not working

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2007, microsoft-office-2007

I'm new to outlook 2007 and I'm trying to rename a category. Acordingly to MS, I can achieve it by just renaming it:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/HA012316361033.aspx

But as soon as I click the OK button, confirming the change, it returns to it's original value. For instance, if I rename the "Blue Category" to "Home" it will accept without erros. But, when I click again in the Categorize icon, I'll see that the "Blue Category" is still there, and my "Home" category does not exist.

Has someone experienced this kind of problem?

TIA,

Bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Blue Category` you refer to is one of the default ones in Outlook.

From the page you linked to:

> The first time that you assign an existing color category to an item, you are prompted to rename the color category.

You may need to assign an entry to it to rename it.

Comment: That's right, but isn't working. When I use for the first time, yes, it prompt's me for a name. But, instead of renaming it, it creates a new category and loose it's color. Probably it'll be necessary to reinstall office...